# On the solution of the functional equation $(x(t))^{p}u(t)=(x\circ f)(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

I am given a real number $p$ and two real valued functions $f(t),u(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ You can assume $u(t)$ and $f(t)$ are as nice as they need to be, including that they're invertible.

I am trying to find a function $x(t)$ that solves the equation $$(x(t))^{p}u(t)=(x\circ f)(t).$$ Ideally, the solution for $x(t)$ is some expression involving $u(t)$ and $f(t).$

Also, observe if $t^{*}$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $p\neq1,$ then $$x(t^{*})=(u(t^{*}))^{\frac{1}{1-p}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure that this is possible to solve without being given $f$. However, since you said that I could assume whatever I liked about $f$, I'm going to assume that
$$f(f(t))=t$$

By the original functional equation,
$$x(t)^pu(t)=x(f(t))$$
and by my assumption,
$$x(f(t))^pu(f(t))=x(f^2(t))=x(t)$$
and so I now have the system of equations
$$x(f(t))=x(t)^pu(t)$$
$$x(f(t))^pu(f(t))=x(t)$$
and by substitution
$$x(t)^{p^2}u(t)^{p}u(f(t))=x(t)$$
$$x(t)^{p^2-1}=\frac{1}{u(t)^pu(f(t))}$$
$$x(t)=\sqrt[p^2-1]{\frac{1}{u(t)^pu(f(t))}}$$

So that is the solution for some cases. A few of these cases include
$$f(x)=c-x, c\in \mathbb R$$
$$f(x)=\pm\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Here is a specific example. If $p=2,$ $f(t)=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$ and $u(t)=1-t^2,$ then the function $x(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ for $t\in[-1,1]$ and $x(t)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ elsewhere seems to work. Can you use this specific $f(t)$ to find $x(t)$ for any value of $p$? Thank you so much for your help. This is a barrier I've encountered in my research that I cannot seem to circumvent.

Comment: Okay, I'll do my best and give it a try, but it is possible that your problem cannot be solved with elementary functions only.

Comment: Anything you're able to do will be tremendously helpful. I plan on posting a question related to the motivation for this problem which I hope you and others will find appealing.

Comment: @user429040 I might be able to find another solvable special case, but a general solution is highly unlikely. I'm sure the motivation is very interesting... I love functional equations, so I couldn't resist giving this one a try.

Answer (score 0):

We can relax the condition on invertibility and get the general solution $$x(t):=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \big(h_{n}(t)\big)^{-1/p^{n}}$$ where $h_{n}:=u\circ f^{n-1}.$